# How to display days and months without of error with alias - mysql

Tags: mysql, union, alias

I'm trying dislpay days and months with unions. But then i have error in below code:

```
(SELECT 1 AS id, a+b AS 'days', 2 AS id2, c+e AS 'months' FROM
((SELECT 0 a UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a, (SELECT 0 b UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20 UNION SELECT 30) d, 
 (SELECT 2 AS id2, c+e AS 'months' FROM (SELECT 0 c UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c, 
(SELECT 0 e UNION SELECT 10) m)
```

It is like: `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

what can i do or change in this code? Thx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in your query. I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 1 AS id, a+b AS 'days', 2 AS id2, months
FROM ((SELECT 0 a UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a, 
      (SELECT 0 b UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20 UNION SELECT 30) d, 
      (SELECT 2 AS id2, c+e AS 'months' 
       FROM (SELECT 0 c UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c, 
             (SELECT 0 e UNION SELECT 10) m
            ) x
      )
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=14bc14a9abfe6a478f68ecd2bbe7ae2b)

Comment: almost but in months column i'd like to get the values for example 0, 10, 1, 11.. 
from that line code `SELECT 0 c UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c, 
             (SELECT 0 e UNION SELECT 10) m
            )`

Comment: @Prochu1991 oops. I forgot to remove the single quotes around `months` when I took out the `c+e AS` part... I've updated the query and the demo